# heroku app crash when listening on process.env.PORT

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

When i deploy this on heroku :

app.js

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port : " + port);
});
```

I get the error logs :

```
2014-11-08T18:05:34.300115+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2014-11-08T18:05:34.300402+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2014-11-08T18:05:34.300404+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303599+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303605+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303607+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303608+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listen (net.js:1064:10)
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303610+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303628+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.app.listen (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:556:24)
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303629+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/www:7:18)
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303630+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303632+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303633+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-11-08T18:05:34.303635+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

but when i listen directly on port 8080 it work, and i cant understand why :

```
var port = 8080;
    app.listen(port, function(){
        console.log("Listening on port : " + port); //it work
    });
```

I have just started using nodejs and I don't really understand why it crashes.

Could someone either explain the cause of this or how to "debug" this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the problem was that express-generator create a /bin/www file that contain :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('toto');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Thats why the port was already used.

Thanks

Comment: You have uncovered the secret jewel that is never documented nor ever spoken of. I have spent DAYS trying to uncover this error. I had no coding error, express-generator had simply done something unspoken of, ahead of me, in a weirdly named file. I'm pissed but I can at least move on now. T.Y. !

Answer (score 1):

The error "EADDRINUSE" means that something is already listening to this port.

I guess that nothing is listening to 8080 on your machine, this is why it works when you set it directly.

Use `console.log(process.env.PORT)` to print the port that you're trying to listen to.
Then check what program is listening to this port using `netstat -tunap`, you should receive something similar to this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State PID/Program name

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:37 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3425/inetd

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:6000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3640/X

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:113 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3425/inetd

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 7586/sshd
```

Kill the relevant program and try again.

To debug nodejs I would recommend [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), very easy to use and it uses chrome developer tools ui.