# Heroku NodeJS - Cannot GET /

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a Heroku server with [BootBot](https://github.com/Charca/bootbot#getting-started) running over it. But I'm having difficulties trying to render a HTML page from it. This is what I'm doing:

```
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'test.html'));
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("The server is running.");
});
```

My root directory has both index.js and test.html.

My Procfile is: 
`web: node --inspect ./index.js`

Everything I've tried sends me to the same `"Cannot GET /test"`.

Is there something I'm missing?

If I set `app.listen(process.env.PORT)`

```
State changed from starting to crashed
2018-11-22T09:48:29.702624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-11-22T09:48:29.606583+00:00 app[web.1]: The server is running.
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608553+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:167
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608557+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608558+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608559+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608561+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::20293
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608563+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1286:14)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608564+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listenInCluster (net.js:1334:12)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608565+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.listen (net.js:1421:7)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608569+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.listen (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608570+00:00 app[web.1]:     at BootBot.start (/app/node_modules/bootbot/lib/BootBot.js:46:28)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608572+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:550:5)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608573+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608574+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608576+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608577+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608579+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event at:
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608580+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1313:8)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608581+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608583+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:11)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608584+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
2018-11-22T09:48:29.608585+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Comment: use `.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of

Comment: I don't have a env file with a declared PORT...

Comment: That's why he placed a `||` if process.env isn't defined, it takes the `3000`

Comment: Heroku defines what port it wants to use with environment variable `PORT`, it might not be 3000 in most cases

Comment: Updated with logs after setting list as you said...

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820425/heroku-app-crash-when-listening-on-process-env-port ?

Answer (score 0):

You need **template engine** like `ejs` or `blade` when you want to render html page from node.Js.

```
npm install ejs --save
```

And these lines to your index.js file

```
// ~ render html files with ejs 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname))); 
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('test.html');
});
```

I hope this helps you. if it does not reach me with the comments.